# PyAudio not found even after reinstall - Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyaudio

I'm trying to install PyAudio for a AI I want to make but I cant. It keeps saying its not found after I have installed it and uninstalled it many times. Last time I ran it this was the error message.
I have tried many online forms but none of them helped.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fares\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\fares\Documents\Something\AI.py", line 64, in <module>
    statement = takeCommand().lower()
  File "c:\Users\fares\Documents\Something\AI.py", line 43, in takeCommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\fares\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\fares\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio        
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure you are not in a virtual environment.

Presuming that you are referring to this [`PyAudio`](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/), I was able to simply install it using standard `pip3 install pyaudio`, and then `import pyaudio` worked successfully on Linux.

However, it is possible that you are experiencing platform-specific setup issues on Windows, as pyaudio contains C extensions, so make sure you have PortAudio installed and the environment variable `PORTAUDIO_PATH` set. For more information, refer to the project's [`setup.py`](https://github.com/iovsiann/pyaudio/blob/master/setup.py) file.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure pyaudio is installed successfully. You could use `pip show pyaudio` in the terminal to query. Pyaudio cannot be simply installed by using `pip pyaudio`. You could download .whl file from [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).